# Using test database when e2e-testing NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, e2e-testing, typeorm

In this project, it uses NestJS along with TypeORM. For real API requests, CRUD operation is being operated on MySQL(which is using AWS RDS).

Now I am trying to use SQLite(In-Memory) to test API results.

I successfully implemented this in Unit Test, as the code below.

First, below is `create-memory-db.ts`, which returns a connection to in-memory SQLite database.

```
type Entity = Function | string | EntitySchema<any>;

export async function createMemoryDB(entities: Entity[]) {
  return createConnection({
    type: 'sqlite',
    database: ':memory:',
    entities,
    logging: false,
    synchronize: true,
  });
}
```

- And by using the exported function above, I successfully ran Unit test, like below.

```
describe('UserService Logic Test', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let connection: Connection;
  let userRepository: Repository<User>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await createMemoryDB([User]);
    userRepository = await connection.getRepository(User);
    userService = new UserService(userRepository);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await userRepository.query('DELETE FROM users');
  });

  // testing codes.
});
```

I am trying to do the same thing on e2e tests. I tried below code.

```
// user.e2e-spec.ts

describe('UserController (e2e)', () => {
  let userController: UserController;
  let userService: UserService;
  let userRepository: Repository<User>;
  let connection: Connection;
  let app: INestApplication;
  const NAME = 'NAME';
  const EMAIL = 'test@test.com';
  const PASSWORD = '12345asbcd';

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await createMemoryDB([User]);
    userRepository = await connection.getRepository(User);
    userService = new UserService(userRepository);
    userController = new UserController(userService);

    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [UserService],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    // await userRepository.query('DELETE FROM users');
  });

  it('[POST] /user : Response is OK if conditions are right', () => {
    const dto = new UserCreateDto();
    dto.name = NAME;
    dto.email = EMAIL;
    dto.password = PASSWORD;

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/user')
      .send(JSON.stringify(dto))
      .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED);
  });
});
```

I cannot create `UserModule` since it doesn't have a constructor with `Connection` parameter.
The code itself has no compile error, but gets results below when e2e test is executed.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index[0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UserRepository is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If UserRepository is exported from a seperate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [/* The module containing UserRepository */]
  })


TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHttpServer' of undefined.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

---

- UPDATE : New error occured after trying below.

```
describe('UserController (e2e)', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let userRepository: Repository<User>;
  let connection: Connection;
  let app: INestApplication;
  const NAME = 'NAME';
  const EMAIL = 'test@test.com';
  const PASSWORD = '12345asbcd';

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await createMemoryDB([User]);
    userRepository = await connection.getRepository(User);
    userService = new UserService(userRepository);

    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UserModule],
    })
      .overrideProvider(UserService)
      .useClass(userService)
      .compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await userRepository.query('DELETE FROM users');
  });

  it('[POST] /user : Response is OK if conditions are right', async () => {
    const dto = new UserCreateDto();
    dto.name = NAME;
    dto.email = EMAIL;
    dto.password = PASSWORD;

    const result = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/user')
      .send(JSON.stringify(dto))
      .expect({ status: HttpStatus.CREATED });
  });
});
```

- I checked if query is working, and was able to see that it is using SQLite database as I wanted. But new error appeared in console.

```
TypeError: metatype is not a constructor.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHttpServer' of undefined.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, I solved this issue by using `TypeOrm.forRoot()` inside the imports field of `Test.createTestingModule`. Below is how I did it.

```
describe('UserController (e2e)', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let userRepository: Repository<User>;
  let app: INestApplication;
  const NAME = 'NAME';
  const EMAIL = 'test@test.com';
  const PASSWORD = '12345asbcd';

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        UserModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'sqlite',
          database: ':memory:',
          entities: [User],
          logging: true,
          synchronize: true,
        }),
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    userRepository = moduleFixture.get('UserRepository');
    userService = new UserService(userRepository);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await userRepository.query('DELETE FROM users');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is really helpful to me! Thanks for your own answer.

Comment: @CasimirCrystal My pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for setup e2e tests that hit endpoints and assert the response body, you can do something like this:

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        if (process.env.APPLICATION_ENV === 'test') {
          return {
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: ':memory:',
            entities: [Entity],
            synchronize: true,
          }
        }
        return {
          // your default options
        };
      },
    }),
  ]
})
```